# vb.net saving 2 dates on phpmyadmin 0000-00-00 and 2-8-2017

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

Im currently using phpmyadmin as my sql database 
i cant seem to save 2 dates on my single table when i insert dates
the other 1 turns to `0000-00-00` and the other one saves the current date

this is my code for insert as you see the "sqlinsert" is in module.
my datestocked wont get insert but my expdate does

```
sqlinsert("tblproducts", "code, prodname, datestocked, prodtype, prodqty, prodprice, expdate",

 "'" + txtprodcode.Text + "', '" + txtprodname.Text + "', '" + datestocked.Text + "','" + txtprodtype.Text + "', '" + txtprodqty.Text + "', '" + txtprodprice.Text + "', '" + expdate1.Text + "'")
```

Guys can you help me organize too im just a newbie here

Comment: That's a [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). String concatenations exposes you to SQL Injection *and* conversion errors.  You'll find dozens of duplicate questions in SO. *Don't* use string concatenation, use parameterized queries. Pass dates as *DateTime* parameters, not text.

Comment: What is `sqlinsert`?

Comment: Also, MySQL and SQL Server are two different things

Comment: @Plutonix in this case the only difference is in the text you need to put in `expdate1` to delete the entire database, or at least all products. With SQL Server it would be `"); drop table tblproducts;--`. I expect the comment syntax would be slightly different for MYSQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# MYSQL - I can't insert a boolean value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611060/c-sharp-mysql-i-cant-insert-a-boolean-value)

Comment: actually guys its my thesis for a pharmacy. it doesnt required any internet its just local server. what do you suggest about the datestock,text? i just wont get insert but the expdate1.text does :)

Comment: I was noting the tag spam

Comment: I suggest that you use SQL Parameters always, then pass and store dates as dates if you want them to act like dates

Comment: how? can you teach me? sorry i dont even know a boolean value

Comment: No, SO is not a tutorial service.  There are gobs and gobs of questions here on SQL Parameters - in fact it is hard to do any research at all on DB ops and not run into them.  One does wonder what you've been learning if it is thesis time and you dont know what a bool is.  Good luck